# Magento and onepage checkout

Tags: magento

I am using Magento and I'm trying to fix a small issue I have with the OnePageCheckout.

I have a single Billing Address and a single Shipping Address, which are both fine.

When selecting a `New Address` under `Shipping Information`, I'd expect the form to be reset, instead it uses the default `Shipping Address`

It just seems odd that you add a New Address and it is pre-populated wit an adress already.

if this is something Magento does out of the box and if so, is there a file(s) I'd need to change?

Many thanks

Comment: it is easy just disable the javascript that does this or is your question "how to program?"

Comment: No my question wasn't how to program. It was simply a question to see if this is something Magento does out of the box and if so, is there a file(s) I'd need to change.

Comment: this is not a thing you can configure from admin and it involves programming, and as it affects frontend then you can see which files and functions you need to change from view-source

Comment: It seems that in `onepage.js` there is a `newAddress` function call that when New Address is called, it loads in `billing-new-address-form`, which just returns the default billing address. within that method, there is a `resetSelectedAddress`, which doesn't seem to do anything. I'd expect the reset function to reset the form..

Comment: Might have fixed it with `Field.clear('billing:firstname')` etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hack a js file and add `Field.clear('billing:firstname')` etc etc so that these fields would be cleared whenever `resetSelectedAddress` was called